# Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'index.php'

Tags: c#, http, localhost, web-hosting, nancy

I am making a project where I need to host a simple website. Nancy seems to be a really easy and straightforward library. Only a couple minutes in and I've got a problem no one has addressed online. How do I host an "index.php" file with Nancy?

I'm hosting a *.php file because I need the php script to run on startup, is this even possible with Nancy?

So far all I've got is a "MainModule" class derived from "NancyModule" and it says `Get["/"] = p => View["index.php"];`. When I navigate to the page however, in my Firefox browser it gives me the error

> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'index.php

how do I fix this with Nancy or is there any other http web hosting libraries for C# I could use?

Comment: Either build your website with PHP, or .NET. Don't mix the two. PHP is not .NET.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found that Recaptcha has an explicit way to use it. This way allowed me to instead of getting the response through PHP I can get it using Javascript.

> var code=document.createElement('p');
>   code.innerHTML=grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1);
>   document.body.appendChild(code);

I put this code in the action of the form, so when the Recaptcha is solved it will display the response as a paragraph and then it would be obtained using an HtmlParser such as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) for C#.